# Multi level data selection in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, facebook

assume we have table of users with 1 million rows. and each user has about 100 friends. so we may come up with a friends table with about 100,000,000 rows.

now if a user post's something and defines it's share and visibility to his friend and friends of his friends... [100*100*100] (like Google+ circles), what is the best way to get this desired list in fastest way possible. (i mean type of selection... if extra tables needed ...)
many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether it's the fastest way, but you can do this by using *Inner Join*. Let's say that you want to retrieve the friends and friends of friends for a user with user_id=1, you can do something like:

```
(select friend_id from friends where user_id = 1) 
union 
(select distinct f2.friend_id from friends f1
  INNER JOIN friends f2 on f2.user_id = f1.friend_id
  where f1.user_id = 1)
```

Again, I am not sure if it's the fastest way, but it's better than using a Sub-Query for Select.

Edit: The first SELECT statement will give you a list of users who are friends of a user with id = 1. The second SELECT statement will give you a list of users who are friends with all the friends of the user with id = 1. The second statement makes use of [INNER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp). And finally, both the result sets are combined using a UNION.

Comment: I've made some changes in the Answer. Hope the explanation will help this time. :)

Comment: Oh, please let me know if you still didn't understand any part of it.